# azure remove a scheduled message from service bus queue

Tags: c#, azure

a message is scheduled using `ScheduledEnqueueTime` into a service bus queue. now I want to delete the message while it is still scheduled (e.g scheduled in 5min but removed after 2min). is this possible? if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the **sequence number** of that message, you can cancel it before `ScheduledEnqueueTime` and that cancelled message can be deleted.

Refer to this [workaround](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/azure-service-bus-peek-delete-scheduled-message-which-has-future/ba-p/1648243) contains the code used to cancel the Scheduled Message from Azure Service Bus Queue.

If the Schedule Time passed, then the queue gets appended with that message and it will even have a **new sequence number**.

Refer [Message Sequencing and timestamps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sequencing) of Scheduled Messages on Azure Service bus Queue for more information.

Comment: the code helped but I am using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, which as far as i can find does not have a CancelScheduledMessageAsync function

Comment: `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` namespace contains the `QueueClient.CancelScheduledMessageAsync` function - same shown in the workaround reference and in this [MSFT Libraries Document](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient.cancelscheduledmessageasync?view=azure-dotnet).